# Unable to start Micro Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with Windows7 OS. I downloaded micro cloud foundary and vm ware player. When I tried to boot micro Cloud Foundry in my system (Intel i7- 2760QM which is 64 bit) through VM player, I got the error "This Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU. but only detected an i686 CPU."

I even enabled  Intel Virtualization Technology through BIOS as suggested in other posts, but I am still getting the same error.

Apart from this, I also checked the processor compatibility with the VMware utility and it shows that it is compatible.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you able to run any 64-bit OS on VMware Player? Have you tried VirtualBox to see if it's specific to VMware Player?

Answer (score 1):

Here are [the hardware requirements](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003945) for VM Player.

It's possible you need to [enable Intel virtualization](http://waynewrighttechtips.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/64bit-guest-on-vmware-esx-4-1-running-on-a-hp-dl380-g5/) in your BIOS.

Comment: Hi, 
AS I mentioned, I have already enabled Intel Virtualisation in BIOS. But it still doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install a 64bit windows.